# What does one call this kind of Japanese toilet in English?

Tags: names, foreign-phrases

[image]This was a warning notice placed near a Japanese toilet, containing one of those inimitable Japanese *Engrish* expressions.

But as these toilets start to become popular in western countries, what is the name for them. the concept is that of a *bidet* and *toilet* combined. I should mention that the top-of-the-range type include hot air dryers too!

Comment: A bidet combined with a toilet sounds like a terrible idea. It would be shooting dirty water back up at you!

Comment: @IanMacDonald It is my understanding that posh Japanese people swear by them!

Comment: Noooo, fantastic invention. The Italians would go crazy for this, think of the space you save in bathrooms.

Comment: @Josh61: No editorializing in comments, please. ^_^

Comment: In Cairo, they think it is weird when toilets do not have water for cleaning. See http://bedawi.com/travel-information/nice-to-know/water-sanitation.html

Comment: @HunterHogan That is also true of Malaysia. The Malays (who are almost universally Islamic) do not use toilet paper. In the urban areas, heavily populated by non-Muslims - Chinese and Indians- toilet paper is usually available. But up-country there is often no toilet paper, but a plastic bucket of water and a bowl. I have never figured out how one executes the procedure. I always make sure I have a supply of tissues. My Chinese relatives always carry toilet paper if they are going out of town.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oh please. The water source is not from the toilet. It's from a separate tube on the side. I'd love one but they are rather expensive in the states. I grew up with bidets and there's nothing better for women, but men can use them also.

Comment: Plus one for the placard :)

Comment: ... But shower toilet is ambiguous. Setups like the following are pretty common on small boats - https://www.litfad.com/stainless-steel-rectangle-shower-stall-with-shower-base-tempered-glass-shower-stall-s-3678243.html?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoeGuBhCBARIsAGfKY7z-A8cifs0MMtSy1hqbH-ocuF02qzwClYmhNf5-p9_dNLsItHZLuOUaAoJbEALw_wcB

Answer (score 3):

*[Shower toilet](http://gb.toto.com/products/productlist/Product/indexByCategory/category/WASHLETs/)* is a common way to call it:

> - Bathing culture has always played a major role in Japanese tradition, which is why this nation has such high standards for hygiene and comfort in the bathroom.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shower%20toilet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshower%20toilet%3B%2Cc0): shower toilet

[Washlet](http://gb.toto.com/products/productlist/Product/indexByCategory/category/WASHLETs/) according to this site.

> - The WASHLET. First launched in 1980, this innovation has revolutionised bathrooms across Japan for nearly three decades. The WASHLET has improved hygiene standards with its warm water cleansing system and through recent developments in air purification, automatic functions and more.

Japanese bidets:

> - The modern toilet in Japan, in English sometimes called Super Toilet, and commonly known in Japanese as [Washlet](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilets_in_Japan#Terminology) (ウォシュレット Woshuretto?) or as warm-water cleaning toilet seat (温水洗浄便座 onsui senjō benza?) is one of the most advanced types of toilet worldwide, showing a dazzling array of features.

[image]

Comment: Did you read the English on the warning notice?

Comment: @WS2 - a very sensible warning!! :))